# Call in Jess manipulated Object from Java

Tags: java, call, jess

)

Im writing my Master Thesis and I´ve to use the JESS Platform for it. I want to ask a question.

For example I have this Java Class which is named as "Main":

```
public class Main {

    private String user = "Joe";
    public String getUser(){ return user; }
    public String setUser(String user){ this.user = user;}
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        Rete rete = new Rete();
        rete.store( "main", main );
        rete.batch( "two.clp" );
    }
}
```

Now I want to call the clp-file and manipulate the Main-Class-Object and do this:

```
(printout t "main.user = " ((fetch main) getUser) crlf) ;; I got for this Joe
((fetch main) setUser "Robin")
(printout t "main.user = " ((fetch main) getUser) crlf) ;; For this I got Robin
```

But now I want to ask you how can I call this manipulated user named "Robin" from a Java code? If I call in Java like this:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        Rete rete = new Rete();
        rete.store( "main", main );
        rete.batch( "two.clp" );
        System.out.println(main.getUser());
    }
```

I got as result "Joe" and not "Robin".
Can u please tell me how I can get (or call) the manipulated version of the Javaobject? And why it is not manipulated im my Java class when I manipulate
the username from Jess to Robin?

I will be thankful for a message. Thanks.

Comment: It would be a good idea to check that the code you post is (a) free from syntax errors and (b) really reproduces the problem you are describing.

Comment: Well you set the value of user in your Main class as "Joe" so of course you will get Joe when you call getUser.  Just like in the 2nd code snippet, you need to call setUser, main.setUser("Robin")

Answer (score 0):

I add the class and the clp.file which I used:

java class:

```
  package Versuch;
import jess.*;

public class Auto {

    private String marke = "";
    private int ps = 0;

    public Auto(String marke, int ps){
        this.marke = marke;
        this.ps = ps;
    }

    public String getMarke() {
        return marke;
    }

    public void setMarke(String marke) {
        this.marke = marke;
    }


    public int getPs() {
        return ps;
    }



    public void setPs(int ps) {
        this.ps = ps;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String getAktuell = "";

        Auto vw = new Auto("VW", 90);
        getAktuell = vw.getMarke();
        System.out.println(" before manipulating " + getAktuell );

        Rete engine = new Rete();
        engine.store("vw", vw);
            try {
                engine.batch("Versuch/rulebase.clp");

                System.out.println(" after manipulating " + getAktuell);



            } catch (JessException e) {
                System.out.println("JESS ERROR");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       


    }

}
```

clp.file:

```
(printout t "vw.getMarke = " ((fetch vw) getMarke) crlf)

((fetch vw) setMarke "Mercedes")


(printout t "vw.getMarke = " ((fetch vw) getMarke) crlf)
```

output:

```
before manipulating VW
vw.getMarke = VW
vw.getMarke = Mercedes
 after manipulating VW
```

The first output and the last output are the system.out.println calls from the java class. the second and the third output are the printout calls from the clp.file. 
Anyone understand why the last call is not the manipulated one?
Sorry im really new to this issue.
I will be very thankful for help.

Comment: oh okay i got the solution. i forgot to ask for the actual value. if i add before the system.out.println("after manipulating" + getAktuell), this --> getAktuell = vw.getMarke(); than i got the manipulated version of the vw object. sometimes it is easier to think about some problem after ask someone :-) thx

Comment: It's always OK to *ask*, but (as you can see clearly now) it is *not* OK to ask a question that doesn't really describe your problem. - You might delete the entire question - it's of no good use for anybody. - And never answer your own question with additional information - this should go into your question, which you can edit.

Comment: Don't "vandalize" your post, please, that gives such a mess. You should instead edit this information into your question, and delete the post with the 'delete' link underneath.